# uninitialized constant ActionView::TemplateHandler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading a rails project from rails 2.3.5 to rails 3.2

I have some plugin code as follows

```
module SpreadsheetOnRails

  class Handler < ::ActionView::TemplateHandler
  include ActionView::TemplateHandlers::Compilable

  def compile(template)
    %Q{controller.response.content_type ||= Mime::XLS
       controller.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment"
       SpreadsheetOnRails::Base.new { |workbook| #{template.source} }.process}
  end

  end

  class Base
    @@temp_file = nil

    def temp_file_path
      unless @@temp_file
        temp = Tempfile.new('spreadsheet-', File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'tmp') )
        @@temp_file = temp.path
        temp.close
      end
      @@temp_file
    end

    def initialize
      yield workbook
   end

    def workbook
      @workbook ||= Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    end

    def process
      workbook.write(temp_file_path)
      File.open(temp_file_path, 'rb') { |file| file.read }
    end
  end
end
```

while running rails s I am getting following error:

> uninitialized constant ActionView::TemplateHandler (NameError)

Any one please help how to re code this method so that it can be compatible to rails 3.2

Comment: remove line: 'include ActionView::TemplateHandlers::Compilable', rails 3.2 removed it [ActionView::TemplateHandlers](https://github.com/innoq/iq_rdf/issues/3)

Comment: @KienThanh sorry that I have not included total code previously, the problem is not with the line 
include ActionView::TemplateHandlers::Compilable

insted with

 class Handler < ::ActionView::TemplateHandler

is there any alternative for this? in rails 3.2

Comment: I think you should check these screen cast [upgrade rails 3 part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1) and   [upgrade rails 3 part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2), [upgrade rails 3 part 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3)

Comment: No Solution found there @KienThanh

Answer (score 0):

`ActionView::TemplateHandler` was deprecated after Rails 2.3.8.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/TemplateHandler

This means that all of the functionality in the `TemplateHandler` class has been removed or moved to a different class in Rails 3.2. You will have to remove the reference, because it's no longer defined.

Check out `actionpack/lib/action_view/template_handler.rb` in Rails 2.3.5. It will help you identify whatever functionality you need to track down in Rails 3.2.